# WiFi (BCM4352) is very slow compared to cable in Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Y50

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my device and I find my wifi speed to be so low compared to what I had on the same network in Windows.

[Wireless info script output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/26056466/).

My device is Lenovo Y50 which uses Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168

Comment: What speed is observed on wired ethernet, and what speed is observed on WLAN? You can expect 802.11AC to max out at ~4-500Mb/s. Ethernet, on the gripping hand, carries on to ~1Gb/s.

Comment: I get around 2Mb/s.  but are you sure that is the best my laptop can do!? btw the problem is actually that it takes around 30 secs to load a website.

Comment: Did you [install `bcmwl-kernel-source`](/a/590450/175814), the canonically recommended driver for your wireless adapter? Your area and frequency spectrum is somewhat crowded with wireless networks. You can try to switch to a different frequency channel. It would probably help to use a better access point since yours only supports very basic features that help improve transmission throughput while the wireless adapter on your computer supports more advanced features.